# Rails 4, get all locals in partial

Tags: partial-views, ruby-on-rails-4.1

How to get all locals as a hash in a partial view.

```
# mainview.html.haml:
= render 'v1', p1: 100, p2: 'some_value', _other_values_
```

in a partial view:

```
# _v1.html.haml
# do something here...

# render another partial view

= render 'another_view', locals: locals # what to write here???
```

How to access ALL variables in locals as a hash.
I don't want to list all variables in locals.

Answer (score 13):

### Use [`local_assigns`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Template.html#method-i-local_assigns).

```
local_assigns #=> { p1: 100, p2: 'some_value', _other_values_ }
```

**_v1.html.haml**

```
= render 'another_view', local_assigns
```